# Rails: solving ambiguity on group using symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have two tables, `Parent` and `Child` and both of them have a field called `name`, if I do:

`Parent.join(:child).group(:name)`

I'll get an error stating that there's an ambiguity in the field `name`. I could do the following

`Parent.join(:child).group('parents.name')`

To solve it, but I'd prefer to use a symbol if that's possible. So, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the scope to automatically add the table name prefix

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self; alias_method :old_group, :group; end
  scope :group, lambda { |g|
    old_group("#{table_name}.#{g}")
  }
end

Parent.join(:child).group(:name)
```

Comment: If you want more out of ActiveRecord, you should check the squeel gem https://github.com/ernie/squeel

Comment: You were right, the `group(:parents => :name)` magic wasn't provided by the Rails', but by the squeel gem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't exactly solve my issue, as it doesn't allow me to specify "childs.name" for instance. I'll take a look into that Squeel gem :)

Comment: Right. If you need more advanced functionality than just resolving ambiguity on the primary table, that solution isn't for you. @jdoe: Care to add an answer that recommends squeel? Seems like a great choice for solving this problem.